# How to listen to press submit button in HTML page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, dom-events

This script emits the `text-entered` after the user press the `enter` key. What I need is to listen to click on the `submit` button in my HTML page. This is the script:

```
// When the user hits return, send the "text-entered"
// message to main.js.
// The message payload is the contents of the edit box.
var textArea = document.getElementById("txt-field");
textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function onkeyup(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // Remove the newline.
    text = textArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    addon.port.emit("text-entered", text);
    textArea.value = '';
  }
}, false);
```

The HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      textarea {
        margin: 10px;
      }
      body {

        background-color:#b3dbfa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <form> 
      Enter URL: <br>
      <input type="text" id="txt-field">
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
  <script src="get-text.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: attach listener to submit button not to textearea! And it is not clear what you mean by send this "When the user hits return, send the "text-entered"
// message to main.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen to clicks in the submit button, simply, in the script, add an event listener to the submit button. But first, add and id to the submit button in the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="submit-btn">
```

In the script:

```
addbtn=document.getElementById("submit-btn");
addbtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Get the text and remove the newline.
var text = formTextArea.value.replace(/\s/,"");    //remove space characters
var level = document.getElementById("levels-list").value;
//send the entered data to the addon to store them
self.port.emit("text-entered", text);
                                                        self.port.emit("selected-level", level);
formTextArea.value = ''; //intialise the text area to empty after adding the item.
}
,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the Addon-On SDK  which is a legacy technology. Mozilla reccomends migrating to WebExtensions.

However to answer your question: With jquery you could do something like

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit
    console.log('do something');
});
```

With  pure javascript you could do something like

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit
    console.log('do something');
})
```

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution to a question that is not tagged with jQuery is often not helpful. If the OP wanted a jQuery based solution, they could have/should have tagged the question with jQuery, or mentioned it in the question. In fact, the [javascript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) explicitly states: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." This is particularly unhelpful, and generally bad practice, for questions regarding extensions. I do note, unlike many people, you also provided the vanilla JavaScript.